# How do I make a hoe in Minecraft Pocket Edition Creative Mode?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know how to make a hoe in survival mode, but not in creative mode. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

An iron hoe is available in the creative inventory under the weapons and tools tab. You don't need to craft anything in creative mode.

Comment: If this answer helped, could you please mark it as accepted by clicking the tick below the votes.

Comment: Maybe +10 is also okey :P

Answer (score 0):

You just can't. Believe it or not it's impossible if you're not playing in v0.14.0 If you are playing in v0.14.0 It's your lucky day! Use 2 Iron and two sticks to make an Iron Hoe.